# My Minecraft won’t let me join my sisters world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

When I go to join my sisters world, something popped up and it said try again later. This has been happening to me everyday. What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried Direct Connect?

Answer (score 0):

You Could use Aternos.com to make a server, me and my brother do that and it works really well.I hope this helps you.

Comment: What is Aternos.com?

Comment: It makes free servers.

Comment: do not use this service, it is laggy and not good, like most free hosts you get long waits, small allocations and bad hardware

Answer (score -1):

Is it an LAN world you are trying to join or an actual server? If you are trying to join her world via LAN, make sure her actual world has LAN enabled. If it is a server, it could be out of date, meaning it was created on an older version. To play on that version, click on the Minecraft Launcher, then click on installations to find the version the server is on.